# Do hidden divs(display:none) and form inputs play role with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm generating(possibly the hard way) sets of inputs ranging from 1 to 15.

The user selects the number of inputs from a drop down. The appropriate set of inputs are then displayed as seen in select_num_fields.php.

```
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
$messageDeveloper = "";
if (isset($_POST['url'])) {

    $commaVar = ",";
    $varCharVar = "VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL";
    $pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['thisID']);
    $url = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?!]/",'', $_POST['url']);
    $cleanOne = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9?!]/",'', $_POST['usernameOne']);
    echo "<pre>";
var_dump($cleanOne);
echo "</pre><br>";


// ------1---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (isset($cleanOne)) {
        // filter everything but numbers and letters preg_replace
        $usernameOne = " $cleanOne $varCharVar $commaVar";

    }
    else if(!isset($cleanOne)) {

        $usernameOne = "";

    }
//other ifs go here to complete a tr 

    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    $sql = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $url (
                 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                 $url varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                 $usernameOne
                 created date,
                 PRIMARY KEY (id),
                 UNIQUE KEY $url ($url)
 )
    ";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($sql);
echo "</pre><br>";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);


    if ($query === TRUE) {
        header("location: creator_test.php?tableDone=1"); 
        exit();
        } else {
        header("location: creator_test.php?tableDone=0"); 
        exit();
        }
}
?>

<form action="creator_test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    <h3 style="padding-left:10px;">&darr; Add New Page To List &darr;</h3>
    <h4>Create page table for database</h4>
<div id="colorBlocks">

    <?php include_once("includes/developer/make_table_developer_form.php");?>
    <br /><br /><span style="clear:both;">Select number of variables and name them. This will also determine table structure.</span>
    <br />
    <br />
<?php include_once("includes/developer/select_num_fields.php");?>


<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" /> 
</form>
```

**make_table_developer_form.php**

```
<p id="di1" style="clear:both;display:table;margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:0;">
            <p id="di2" style="float:left;width:55px;text-align:right;margin-top:0;">
                URL:
            </p>
            <p id="di3" style="float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top:0;">
                <input name="url" type="text" id="url" size="64" />
            </p>
    </p>
    <p id="di4" style="clear:both;display:table;margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:0;">

        <p id="di5" style="float:left;width:55px;text-align:right;margin-top:0;">
                Status:
        </p>
        <p id="di6" style="float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-top:0;">
                <select name="status" id="status">
                      <option value="Ready">Ready</option>
                      <option value="Live">Live</option>
                      <option value="Hold">Hold</option>
                </select>
        </p>
    </p>
```

**select_num_fields.php**

```
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="div1">1</option>
    <option value="div2">2</option>
    <option value="div3">3</option>
    <option value="div4">4</option>
    <option value="div5">5</option>
    <option value="div6">6</option>
    <option value="div7">7</option>
    <option value="div8">8</option>
    <option value="div9">9</option>
    <option value="div10">10</option>
    <option value="div11">11</option>
    <option value="div12">12</option>
    <option value="div13">13</option>
    <option value="div14">14</option>
    <option value="div15">15</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>

 <div id="div1" class="group" >
<input name="usernameOne" type="text" id="usernameOne" size="40"/><br />
</div>

 <div id="div2" class="group" >
<input name="usernameOne" type="text" id="usernameOne" size="40"/><br />
<input name="usernameTwo" type="text" id="usernameTwo" size="40"/><br />
</div>//ect.
```

My issue is that none of the username variables are passed. Keep in mind the sciprt I'm running makes either **div1** `display:none` or **div2** `display:none;`

So when I dump the variable to see whats going on the first variable url is passed, but the usernames aren't. Is there an issue with using this method to display inputs? Am I missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: As a note. I just left out the javascript and was able to get it to display the variables. I think we've narrowed it down to either the javascript or the display:none as the issue. Anyone else have any experience with this?

Comment: Have you tried to add, for each `display: none;` input, an `<input type="hidden" />`? And then before submitting the form you'd duplicate the values into the hidden inputs, which would for sure be submitted. Or, simpler, try other ways of hiding your inputs, such as `visibility: hidden;` and `opacity: 0;`. If them still taking room in the document despite being invisible is a problem, then you can set their height to 0 or put them in `position: absolute;`. PS: Try to avoid `<br>` when possible. Really.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to make sense of exactly what your code is doing but hope this helps:

HTML styles will have no effect on which fields are posted, so that isn't the problem. What will prevent a field being posted though with the form is if the "disabled" attribute is set.

What may be part of the problem is you have two inputs with the same name (usernameOne). If you fill in the first but leave the second blank, the second blank field will overwrite the first. As a side note, while you can have multiple inputs with the same name, you shouldn't have multiple inputs with the same ID. An element's ID should always be unique.

Comment: Instead of hiding/showing the groups, maybe just hide/show the second user input?

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the input name in the form which means only the final one will be posted to the server. For your particular use-case I would suggest using multiple forms and submit buttons. Or you would need to set the disabled attribute to all the input fields in the hidden divs.